# alarm service receiver android

Tags: java, android

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
        minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
    }
}
```

Hey guys, So the issue here is that i need to create a class for this receiver and i have no clue on how to do so. i need this to be linked with my main activity class as the variables are over there(ex minochaDevicePolicyManager). How to do so. Yes i tried to look up on the net and i came up with this website but it wasnt really helpful.
How to do so?
Here is my alarm service in the main activity -> onCreate

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60, alarmIntent);
```

Now how to do it. i need a class for my receiver and it has to be linked to the main activity

Comment: Please provide code of how you are instantiating minochaDevicePolicyManager within your MainActivity

Comment: If you're asking where to put your `public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {` code, just please it somewhere in your main activity, I recommend somewhere beneath your main activity methods.

Comment: don't forget to register your receiver in your manifest.xml !

Comment: Hey strider,
i did that and got this error
  Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.todaysfuture.dynpin.MainActivity$MyBroadcastReceiver has no zero argument constructor

Comment: CodeChimp here it is

 minochaDevicePolicyManager=(DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

Answer (score 0):

You need a singleton object available from both MainActivity and MyBroadcastReceiver.

Add a new **App.java** class as follows

```
package ....;

import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {
    public DevicePolicyManager minochaDevicePolicyManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        minochaDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_‌​POLICY_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

Then modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` to reference the App class

```
<application
    android:name="App" ...>
```

Then within both your MainActivity and MyBroadcastReceiver when you want to use the DevicePolicyManager instance do the following;

Add a member variable at the top of both classes

```
private fullpackagename.App app;
```

Get a reference to it within your MainActivity OnCreate and MyBroadcastReceiver OnReceive methods using the following

```
this.app = ((App) getApplicationContext());
```

To use the instance just refer to app.minochaDevicePolicyManager

```
app.minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
```

Comment: "Get a reference to it within your OnCreate or OnReceive" the onReceive isnt linked with the MainActivity at all.
it shows it has never been used(greyed out)

Comment: Within your MainActivity add the this.app = ((App) getApplicationContext()); to the OnCreate.  Within your MyBroadcastReceiver add the line to the OnReceive.

Comment: Hey,
Im totally confused. what do i do with the onReceive?

Comment: Within your current OnReceive within MyBroadcastReceiver do the following;
public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
this.app = ((App) getApplicationContext());
app.minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);

Comment: also _minochaDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_‌​POLICY_SERVICE);_ the DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE isnt resolved

Comment: DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE isnt resolved - you'll need to add the same import as you had in the MainActivity to the App class (best to add them all then remove ones still not used).

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are asking for a single reference to `minochaDevicePolicyManager` since I'm guessing you are not using it that frequently there's no reason you can't just create a new instance within the MyBroadcastReceiver using the `context` passed in.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);

        DevicePolicyManager minochaDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_‌​POLICY_SERVICE);

        minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
    }
}
```